# Which foods give buffs, and what are those buffs?

Tags: starbound

I've read that some foods in Starbound give buffs, and as I'm starting my shipboard farm, I'm trying to figure out what I should grow. Which foods give buffs?

Comment: I answered this question in your other question ._. 

http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146972/which-food-items-heal-you-and-by-how-much

Your princess is in another castle

Comment: A good source for food, drinks and their effects is the [Starbound Food & Drinks List](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApIokJ_zInZLdE81S1dDOC1yb2p1X2p3TUZxNmkyUnc&usp=drive_web#gid=0)

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is very relevant to the other question you asked, mentioned in my comment to your question, this is literally a copy paste of that answer I gave you (buffs included, +foodbar included, +energy & +health replenisment/regen included)

***`FARMING SECTION`***

***==================================================***

**Avesmingo**

Avesmingo is a cooking ingredient for food. It replenishes 4 hunger bars upon consumption. It can be found in Forest Biomes.

```
•   Food – 40
```

**CoralCreep**

Coralcreep is an ingredient for food crafted though cooking. It can also be consumed to replenish two and a half hunger bars.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Grapes**

Grapes are a type of food. It is a crop that can be grown by farming, it's also an ingredient in other recipes. It can be found growing on Forest Biomes.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Rice**

Rice is a type of food. It is a known ingredient in cooking recipes. It can be found growing in Forest Biomes.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Banana**

Banana is a type of food. It is a crop that can be grown by farming; it's also an ingredient in other recipes. It replenishes two and a half hunger bars upon consumption.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Corn**

Corn is a type of food. It is a crop that can be grown by farming; it's also an ingredient in other recipes. It replenishes 2 hunger bars upon consumption.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Kiwi**

Kiwi is an ingredient for food crafted though cooking. It can be found growing on Desert Biomes.
Kiwi takes roughly 5min for growth stage 1 and 10min to be ripe at growth stage 2.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Sugar**

Sugar is a type of food. It is a known ingredient in cooking recipes. It can be found growing on Desert Biomes.
Sugar takes roughly 5min for growth stage 1 and 10min to be ripe at growth stage 2.

**Beakseed**

This seed is used in the recipe for Curried Beakseed. It can be found in Forest Biomes.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**CurrentCorn**

Currentcorn can be found growing on Desert Biomes. It is grown using Currentcorn Seeds

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Neonmelon**

Neonmelon can be found in mini-rainbow biomes and can be grown with Neon Melon Seeds.

```
•   Food – 30
```

**Tomato**

Tomato is a food item. It grows as a crop from tomato seeds. It can be found growing in Forest Biomes. When consumed, it replenishes two and a half hunger bars.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**BoltBulb**

Boltbulb is a Crop that Glitch Players are able to grow from the start, since they have 3 Boltbulb Seeds in their Shiplocker. It can also be found growing naturally in Desert Biomes. It will replenish 2 and a half hunger bars. Boltbulb takes roughly 5min for growth stage 1 and 10min to be ripe at growth stage 2.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Diodia**

Diodia is a type of food. It is a known ingredient in cooking recipes.
Diodia takes roughly 20 minutes to become ripe.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Oculemon**

Oculemon is a type of food. It is a crop that can be grown by farming; it's also an ingredient in other recipes. Can be found in the Eyeball mini biome growing in the ground or a drop from one of the eyeball trees.
Note: Despite what the description says it is currently safe to eat for all races.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**ToxicTop**

Toxictop is a food item used as an ingredient in cooking, and for making toxic furniture. It can be harvested from crops grown using toxictop seeds. It can be found growing wild in Toxic Biomes.
Toxictop takes roughly two hours to become ripe.
Effects:

```
•   Food – 25
```

**BoneBoo**

Boneboo is a delicious arid fruit which can be eaten directly as food or used as an ingredient to concoct other tasty morsels. It can be found in underground Tar Mini Biomes, which are located on Desert, and Forest planets. When consumed, it restores two and a half hunger bars. Boneboo takes roughly 10 minutes to become ripe.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**DirtUrchin**

Dirturchin is a type of food. It is a crop that can be grown by farming, it's also an ingredient in other recipes.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**PearlPeas**

Pearlpea is one of many crops. It is a known ingredient in cooking recipes.
Pearlpea takes roughly 20min for growth stage 1 and 50min to be ripe at growth stage 2.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**WartWeed**

--No Description on Source--

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Carrot**
Carrot is a type of food. It is a crop that can be grown by farming, it's also an ingredient in other recipes. It can be found growing on Forest Biomes, and in Abandoned Mines.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Eggshoot**

Eggshoot is one of many crops. It is a known ingredient in cooking recipes such as the very powerful Pearlpea Pancakes. Can be found growing in Forest Biomes.
Eggshoot takes roughly 10 minutes to become ripe.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Pineapple**

Pineapples are an ingredient for food crafted though cooking. It can also be consumed to replenish two hunger bars.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Wheat**

Wheat is a type of food. It is a known ingredient in cooking recipes.
Wheat takes roughly 10 minutes to become ripe.

**Chili**

Harvested from Chili Seed. Can be found growing in Forest Biomes. Chili takes roughly two hours to become ripe.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Feathercrown**

Feathercrown is one of many crops. It can be found growing on Forest Biomes.
Feathercrown takes roughly 5min for growth stage 1 and 10min to be ripe at growth stage 2.
It replenishes 2 hunger bars upon consumption.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Potato**

Potato is a type of food. It is a crop that can be grown by farming, it's also an ingredient in other recipes. It can be found growing in Forest Biomes.

```
•   Food – 25
```

***`COOKING SECTION`***

***==================================================***

**Alien Burger**

Alien Burger is a type of food. It is craftable through cooking. The burger can satisfy the hunger meter and restore health! Better than a big Mac.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Energy – 25

•   Health REGEN – 3
```

**Bread**

Bread is a type of food created through cooking using the Wooden Cooking Table, combining 2 wheat.

```
•   Food – 70

•   Energy REPLENISHMENT – 10

•   Health REPLENISHMENT – 15
```

**Coralcreep Curry**

Coralcreep Curry is a food crafted through cooking using the Wooden Cooking Table, combining 1 chili, 1 Coralcreep, and 2 rice.
This recipe is given to Hylotl players by default as one of their six Starter Recipes.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Energy REPLENISHMENT – 15

•   Health REGEN– 3
```

**Raw Ham (Pork)**

Raw Ham (also known as Raw Alien Ham) is found by unknown methods. It can be cooked to produce an edible form of ham.

--Listed on source, unknown effect--

**Cooked Bacon**

Cooked Bacon is a type of Food. It is craftable through Cooking at a Camp Fire.

```
•   Food – 35
```

**Brineapple**

Brineapple is a type of food created through cooking using the Wooden Cooking Table, combining 1 pineapple, 1 coralcreep, and 1 sugar.
This recipe is given to Hylotl players by default.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Sugar Rush (Run boost, +25% height on jump)

•   Health REGEN – 2
```

**Burger**

Burger is a type of food. It is created through cooking.
Alongside full hunger restoration, the burger also adds a healing buff to the player.
It is given to human players by default as one of their six Starter Recipes.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Energy REPLENISHMENT - 15

•   Health REGEN – 3
```

**RiceCake**

Ricecake is a type of food created through cooking using the Wooden Cooking Table, combining 2 Rice.
This recipe is given to Hylotl players by default.

```
•   Food – 50

•   Energy REPLENISHMENT - 10

•   Health REPLENISHMENT– 5
```

**Bananacon**

Bananacon is a type of food that is created through cooking.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Energy - 15

•   Health REGEN – 2
```

**Burrito**

Burrito is a type of food that is created through cooking.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Energy - 15

•   Health REGEN – 3
```

**Ham Sandwich**

Ham Sandwich is a type of food that is created through cooking.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Energy - 15

•   Health REGEN – 3
```

**Roast Banana**

Roast Banana is a type of food that is created through cooking.

```
•   Food – 50

•   Energy REPLENISHMENT - 10

•   Health REPLENISHMENT– 5
```

**Banana Bread**

Consumed primarily by the Apex, Banana Bread is a type of food that is created through cooking.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Sugar Rush (Run boost, +25% height on jump)

•   Health REGEN – 3
```

**Cake**

Cake is a type of food that is created through cooking.
It was officially confirmed by Mollygos in a daily update. [1](http://starbounder.org/Food) 'Eat Cake' was also the job Mollygos was permanently assigned on the development roadmap (which she completed 596%).

```
•   Food – 100

•   Doping (Run boost, +50% height on jump)

•   Health REGEN – 3
```

**Meatballs**

Meatballs are a type of food. It is created through cooking.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Energy REPLENISHMENT - 10

•   Health REGEN – 1
```

**Toffee Apple**

Toffee Apple is a type of food that is created through cooking.

```
•   Food – 70

•   Sugar Rush (Run boost, +25% height on jump)

•   Health REGEN – 1
```

**Banana Cream Pie**

Banana Cream Pie is a type of food that is created through cooking.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Sugar Rush (Run boost, +25% height on jump)

•   Health REGEN – 3
```

**Carrot Cake**

Carrot Cake is a type of food that is created through cooking.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Sugar Rush (Run boost, +25% height on jump)

•   Health REGEN – 3
```

**Pizza**

Pizza is a type of food that is created through cooking.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Energy REPLENISHMENT - 25

•   Health REGEN – 3

•   Food Depletion Surpressed
```

**Tropical Punch**

Tropical Punch is craftable food item.

```
•   Food – 25
```

**Battered Banana**

Battered Banana is a type of food that is created through cooking. It is also an Apex starter recipe.

```
•   Food – 100

•   Energy REPLENISHMENT - 10

•   Health REGEN – 2
```

**Chocolate**

Chocolate is a basic food crafted though cooking, allowing one to refill hunger.

```
•   Food – 50

•   Sugar Rush (Run boost, +25% height on jump)

•   Health REGEN – 2
```

**Pizza Slice**

Pizza Slice is a type of food that is created through cooking

```
•   Food – 100

•   Energy REPLENISHMENT - 15

•   Health REGEN – 3
```

[Source](http://starbounder.org/Food)

Comment: A good source for food, drinks and their effects is the  "Starbound Food & Drinks List":

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApIokJ_zInZLdE81S1dDOC1yb2p1X2p3TUZxNmkyUnc&usp=drive_web#gid=0

Comment: very good source. place it as an answer, has more value than mine. I only siphoned my information from a wiki