# How do I regenerate my health?

Tags: starbound

I'm not very good at the whole combat thing in this game. In fact, I'm *really* not very good at it. Having died multiple times before even finding a tree to get wood from, I finally got some wood and narrowly escaped with my life.

How do I regenerate my health?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Wiki](http://starbound.gamepedia.com/Health):

> Using a Bandage, Medkit, or Red Stim Pack.
>   Sleeping in any Bed, tent or any object it is possible to sleep on.
>   Eating certain foods can temporary increase health regeneration.

For foods that heal, see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146972/which-food-items-heal-you-and-by-how-much).

Beds are easy to craft and you can find tents and sacrificial altars, both of which act like beds while exploring.

Personally I use sacrificial altar (while out of combat), seems to be one of the fastest beds to heal) and bandages (while in combat), because bandages are extremely easy to acquire once you gain the ability to travel to the galaxies far far away.

Comment: To clarify, once you've built a crafting table and some wood planks, a bed is very easy to make. And bandages can be made with raw plant fiber, no table or anything required.

Comment: Might be useful to also mention the [Nanowrap Bandages](http://starbounder.org/Nanowrap_Bandage), which you can make by hand from regular bandages and some pixels once you get the [Portable Pixel Printer](http://starbounder.org/Portable_Pixel_Printer). They heal quite a bit more than the regular ones, and are rather crucial to survival in higher-level planets, when your HP is far too high for basic bandages to matter.

Answer (score 3):

Starbound doesn't have any passive health regeneration (at the beginning, at least), so you'll need to build some healing items. Early in the game, you have two at your disposal.

- a *bandage* can be made with 4 pieces of plant fibre and no other tools. Once used, it will recover some health for you fairly quickly, but not instantaneously. Bandages are single-use, so unless you establish a renewable source of fibre, you'll run out eventually.
- a *wooden bed* can be built at a crafting table. This requires a total of 15 logs, refined into planks. Resting in a bed will slowly recover health at no cost, but you won't be able to do anything else.

If you're lucky, you may find some *red stimpacks* in random containers. These are limited, but effective at recovering your HP.